# pvlib.irradiance.disc returns seemingly incorrect values on certain days

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pvlib

I am trying to use the DISC model, to calculate DNI from GHI. It seems to return logical values on certain days, yet on others, it seems to be massively off the mark. I calculate DHI afterwards, using the standard formula of GHI - DNI * cos(θ).

Here's a sample of my dataframe for reference:

|  | pressure | zenith | ghi | dni | dhi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-21 09:00:00+02:00 | 1022 | 79.611284 | 148.975472 | 632.731814 | 34.877836 |
| 2021-02-21 10:00:00+02:00 | 1022 | 73.237092 | 322.780190 | 792.803789 | 94.126078 |
| 2021-02-21 11:00:00+02:00 | 1022 | 68.484954 | 501.550757 | 763.726566 | 221.457448 |
| 2021-02-21 12:00:00+02:00 | 1022 | 65.795320 | 521.414153 | 865.344120 | 166.625191 |
| 2021-02-21 13:00:00+02:00 | 1022 | 65.466171 | 516.448304 | 878.623028 | 151.617274 |
| 2021-02-21 14:00:00+02:00 | 1022 | 67.536285 | 412.165474 | 866.599138 | 81.039446 |
| 2021-02-21 15:00:00+02:00 | 1021 | 71.767697 | 292.985096 | 778.455371 | 49.429408 |
| 2021-02-21 16:00:00+02:00 | 1021 | 77.744154 | 124.146227 | 223.897390 | 76.617876 |
| 2021-02-22 09:00:00+02:00 | 1022 | 79.276500 | 114.214529 | 277.318106 | 62.614056 |
| 2021-02-22 10:00:00+02:00 | 1023 | 72.888793 | 248.292454 | 634.777628 | 61.523563 |
| 2021-02-22 11:00:00+02:00 | 1023 | 68.124958 | 387.336228 | 855.994144 | 68.406867 |
| 2021-02-22 12:00:00+02:00 | 1023 | 65.429755 | 516.448304 | 878.656364 | 151.095472 |
| 2021-02-22 13:00:00+02:00 | 1023 | 65.104368 | 511.482455 | 887.843374 | 137.729993 |
| 2021-02-22 14:00:00+02:00 | 1023 | 67.187466 | 407.199624 | 866.444561 | 71.264128 |
| 2021-02-22 15:00:00+02:00 | 1023 | 71.437557 | 218.497359 | 329.880024 | 113.484015 |
| 2021-02-22 16:00:00+02:00 | 1023 | 77.433660 | 99.316982 | 74.722948 | 83.059519 |
| 2021-02-23 09:00:00+02:00 | 1028 | 78.938277 | 49.658491 | 0.000000 | 49.658491 |
| 2021-02-23 10:00:00+02:00 | 1028 | 72.537193 | 99.316982 | 0.000000 | 99.316982 |
| 2021-02-23 11:00:00+02:00 | 1028 | 67.761859 | 153.941321 | 25.383509 | 144.334754 |
| 2021-02-23 12:00:00+02:00 | 1028 | 65.061403 | 238.360756 | 135.501848 | 181.226844 |
| 2021-02-23 13:00:00+02:00 | 1028 | 64.740241 | 233.394907 | 116.897570 | 183.512050 |
| 2021-02-23 14:00:00+02:00 | 1028 | 66.836873 | 188.702265 | 67.331661 | 162.217334 |
| 2021-02-23 15:00:00+02:00 | 1028 | 71.106160 | 168.838869 | 113.359190 | 132.131384 |
| 2021-02-23 16:00:00+02:00 | 1028 | 77.122298 | 79.453585 | 3.785011 | 78.610017 |
| 2021-02-24 09:00:00+02:00 | 1029 | 78.596748 | 84.419434 | 53.955268 | 73.751777 |
| 2021-02-24 10:00:00+02:00 | 1028 | 72.182423 | 168.838869 | 150.012792 | 122.936847 |
| 2021-02-24 11:00:00+02:00 | 1028 | 67.395784 | 263.190001 | 299.151463 | 148.207170 |
| 2021-02-24 12:00:00+02:00 | 1028 | 64.690387 | 327.746039 | 415.466900 | 150.129973 |
| 2021-02-24 13:00:00+02:00 | 1028 | 64.373905 | 322.780190 | 377.550453 | 159.490967 |

As you can see, on the 21st and 22nd days, it finds DNI without much hassle. Yet on the 23rd, it seems to return illogical values. Also, I do correct the pressure input, by multiplying it by 100.

Here's the relevant codeline of the actual irradiance.disc call:

```
for x in df.index:
    df['dni'][x] = irradiance.disc(df['ghi'][x],
                                   df['zenith'][x],
                                   x,
                                   df['pressure'][x]*100)['dni']
```

Afterwards, even though it's not as relevant, I calculate the DHI like this:

```
for x in df.index:
    df['dhi'][x] = df['ghi'][x] - df['dni'][x] * math.cos(np.deg2rad(df['zenith'][x]))
```

I haven't yet been able to find the source of this problem, I only suspect it might have something to do with the limits of input pressure to the DISC model.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Augustas Krivickas -- First, there's no need to use loops like the code in your question uses -- these pvlib functions are vectorized, meaning you can pass in the full time series inputs and calculate the output time series all in one function call.  Second, can you elaborate on what about the returned DNI values seems illogical?  Are they lower than you'd expect?  If so, is it not explained by the 23rd just being an overcast day, as evidenced by the low GHI values?

Comment: Hello @kevinsa5,
Thanks for pointing it out they are vectorized, simply looking at the pvlib documentation, I was unsure if irradiance.disc was, so I just went with the safe route right off the bat.
As for the data: the references i looked at usually said, that usually, GHI is 80% of the DNI * cos(θ) component, and only 20% of the DHI component. And it makes sense to me physically, seeing as DNI is the direct beam irradiance. And looking at the other days - the 21st and 22nd, the DNI returned by the disc function is always higher than DHI, unless GHI is a really low value.

Comment: @kevinsa5
Yet even taking into account, that the GHI values on the 23rd were low, they weren't lower than some of the values in the 21st and 22nd, yet on those two days DNI was always returned higher than GHI (except the last hour of the 22nd, yet the GHI there was lower than 100, so that might have something to do with the internal DISC calculation). So It being an overcast day shouldn't have that much of an input into it, as far as I understand. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Hi @Augustas Krivickas -- that rule of thumb that ~80% of GHI is DNI*cos(zenith) really only applies to clear-sky conditions.  Remember that GHI,DNI,DHI are _as measured on the ground_ -- so irradiance that starts out as beam in the upper atmosphere, but scatters off a cloud on the way down, turns into DHI by the time it hits the ground.  On a very cloudy day, can you even see where the sun is?  In such conditions, DNI must be nearly zero, and so GHI must be "mostly" DHI.

When you compare DNI across days with similar GHI, don't forget to account for cos(zenith).

Comment: Here is a real example from NREL's SRRL, one of the highest-quality irradiance measurement groups in the world.  The first part of the day is clear-sky, showing high DNI and low DHI.  In the afternoon it becomes cloudy, which sends DNI to zero (with brief spikes for breaks in the clouds), and DHI making up the majority of GHI.  https://midcdmz.nrel.gov/apps/plot.pl?site=BMS;start=20200101;edy=24;emo=2;eyr=2021;zenloc=222;amsloc=224;year=2021;month=2;day=16;time=1;inst=3;inst=66;inst=76;type=plot;preset=0;first=3;math=0;second=-1;value=0.0;global=-1;direct=-1;diffuse=-1;user=0;axis=1

Comment: @kevinsa5 Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As @kevinsa5 pointed out, the data seems correct, as GHI is not made up of mostly DNI on cloudy days.